# JavaFX Slider change width (thickness)

Tags: java, css, javafx, slider, javafx-8

My problem is that the default `Slider` is too thin.
Is there a way to make the `Slider` (width) bigger?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JavaFX most of the styling can be done via CSS.

You can use the `.slider .track` and the `.slider .thumb` style classes in your CSS file. In this style classes you can use the `-fx-pref-width` and `-fx-pref-height` attributes:

```
.slider .track {
    -fx-pref-height:20;
}

.slider:vertical .track {
    -fx-pref-width:20;
}

.slider .thumb {
    -fx-pref-height: 30;
    -fx-pref-width: 30;
}
```

Or alternatively you can use the `-fx-padding` attribute:

```
.slider .track {
    -fx-padding: 10;
}

.slider .thumb {
    -fx-padding: 15;
}
```

This will produce horizontal and vertical `Slider`s like these:

[image]

In any case, you can refer to the [JavaFX 8 default stylesheet (modena.css)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) and the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#slider).

You can also use the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) about styling JavaFX with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Because I spent way to much time researching a similar problem, here is how you get rid of the track and it's "clickability":

```
CSS:
.slider .track {
    visibility: hidden;
}

// You'll probably want this in the code also to swallow all keyboard events:

slider.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("KeyEvent NO!");
        event.consume();
    }
});
```